# Select records from current month without full table scan

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database with over 4 million records and i want to select current month records without doing a full table scan.

I created date  index on the database but the performance is still very slow

```
SELECT sum(scores) as total
FROM customers 
WHERE YEAR(date_created) = YEAR(CURDATE())
      AND MONTH(cam_date) = MONTH(CURDATE());
```

The code works but takes time to load

Comment: Please post TEXT results of A) EXPLAIN SELECT ...your.query...; B) SHOW CREATE TABLE total; and C) SHOW INDEX FROM total; for analysis and suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You may use:

```
SELECT sum(scores) as total FROM customers WHERE date_created > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) ORDER BY id DESC;
```

Comment: its giving me records for the last 30 days not for current month

Comment: check the edits.. you can replace id field.. plz try to grasp somethings from your end also

Comment: @RakeshH Then show something that works from the beginning of the month, please

Answer (score 0):

You could try separating the date into three separate columns - year, month and date. Searching on integers would be faster, then just date, but changing all of 4 million records to this scheme could take some time.

Answer (score 0):

In the absence of the additional information requested Jun 8, 2019, please try this technique,

```
SET @my_bom=CURDATE();
SET @my_now=NOW();
SELECT date_add(@my_bom,interval -DAY(@my_bom)+1 DAY) INTO @my_bom;
SELECT sum(scores) AS total
FROM customers 
WHERE date_created BETWEEN @my_bom AND @my_now;
```

Idea picked up from this seed URL,
https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2014/04/09/mysql-finding-first-day-and-last-day-of-a-month/

This technique will avoid the NON-DETERMINISTIC nature of your existing query and your index should be used in the processing. To be verified with EXPLAIN.

View profile, Network profile for Utility Script downloads that are FREE to use when needed to enhance performance.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for your contribution,This is how i solved it:

i ran this query on the database for creating index,

`CREATE INDEX date_index ON customers(date_created);`

Then i used this code for selecting the sum

`SELECT sum(scores) as total
FROM customers WHERE  date_created>= LAST_DAY(CURDATE()) + INTERVAL 1 DAY - INTERVAL 1 MONTH
  AND date_created< LAST_DAY(CURDATE()) + INTERVAL 1 DAY`

Comment: Please try my answer of Jun 23,19  and you will avoid 4 million OS calls to CURDATE() and the calculations 4 million times.  Would like to know the duration difference if you have time to determine the difference.  Thanks